# How should I produce to JMS endpoints on a dynamic list of other nodes?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

From my hub system, I want to be able to communicate with a dynamic list of other nodes. I'm going to have a broker on each system and a static queue name. Thus I can address each node by targeting its broker. I have something working, using an endpoint per destination, but the [Camel JMS doc](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html#JMS-Reuseendpointandsendtodifferentdestinationscomputedatruntime) implies that's not a great idea. I'll probably have less than 100 endpoints but I'm keen to see if there's a better way.

A dynamic recipient list would be perfect if I could specify the broker URI as part of the endpoint URI, but I can't see how to do that.

It'd probably be more sensible to use a single central broker and have the other nodes pick up from that, but I have a requirement that those nodes must not need to be configured with a central location. So the messages must be sent out, rather than collected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well - just an idea - how about extending the JmsComponent by adding a 'brokerUrl' property and creating the ConnectionFactory for the JmsComponent during runTime (it has a setter for that). And if the component get's called, it creates the connectionFactory. It would be good to ensure that these factories are only generated once for each url. This way your endpoint would be sg like: <to uri="myJmsComponent:queue:myqueue?brokerUrl="tcp://foo.bar:61616"/>.

Comment: Seems fairly equivalent to what I have working, although cleaner. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it could be easier if you plug JNDI registry in your application. Apache ActiveMQ already comes with an integrated lightweight JNDI provider. Alternatively, you can use some app server's JNDI or another lightweight implementation. Then fill this registry with broker destinations (ConnectionFactory instances).

Initialize JndiTemplate in your context:

```xml
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <property name="environment">
    <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://localhost:61616</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

After that you can specify **сonnectionFactory** property on endpoint in Dynamic Router using destinations from your registry:

```java
public class FooDynamicRouter {

  private AbstractApplicationContext ctx;
  private JndiTemplate jndiTemplate;

  @Consume(uri = "activemq:outgoing")
  @DynamicRouter
  public String route(@XPath("/destination/code") String code, Document body) {
     if (code != null) {
       if (!ctx.containsBean("cf"+code)) {
          ctx.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("cf"+code, jndiTemplate.lookup("cf"+code));
       }    
       return "jms:queue:foo?connectionFactory=cf"+code;
     } else {
       return null;
     }
  }
}
```

Perhaps there is simplier way to bind your JNDI registry entries with application context in runtime, but I didn't find it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you've managed to pick the exact opposite way of doing it I'd have chosen (Spring, annotations, code embedded in body) but I can see how it'd get the job done.